# Open Data Day Involvement/Promotion

Tags: discussion

This weekend is Open Data Day 2016, with events convening globally. Hopefully many participants will be able to utilize ODSE, I'm sure some will. How can user involvement be encouraged and maximized?
I keep trying to think of a good place to mention the site on the Open Data Day wiki...thoughts?
The Twitter account could be used for promotion all week....
Next year this could be on the agenda ahead of time (apologies, ODD is < one week from now), make a coordinated campaign of promotion. Something like having the twitter account tweet out individual events and/or datasets to said events. That is certainly not a concrete use, just spit balling off the top of my head.
I think ODSE could gain some real traction here if done properly.
I'm already planning on name dropping ODSE in many of the civic hacking/open gov channels I have access to to.
Any and all thoughts are welcome.