# another year, another open data day, another opportunity

Tags: discussion

Open data day is right around the corner. still a great opportunity to engage/promote/grow this site. if anyone wants to do anything or has some ideas, lets talk about it.
If not, I'll just be pitching the site at the event I attend.

Comment: w00t! w00t! w00t!

Comment: another another year.....

Comment: also, see here for another another another year https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/open-data-day-involvement-promotion